# Problem with combination of Bluetooth and RF 434MHz with Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, bluetooth, rf

I want to receive text from Bluetooth from an android phone to Arduino Mega. Then I want to send that text to other Arduino UNO through RF 434MHz.
Here is my code for Transmitter.

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  vw_setup(2000); 
}

void loop()
{
  String voice;
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  while (Serial.available())
  {                 //Check if there is an available byte to read
    delay(10); //Delay added to make thing stable 
    char c = Serial.read(); //Conduct a serial read
    if (c == '#') {break;} //Exit the loop when the # is detected after the word
    voice += c; //Shorthand for voice = voice + c
  }  
  if (voice.length() > 0) 
  {
    Serial.println(voice);  
  }
  send(voice);
  delay(1000);
}

void send (char *message)
{
  vw_send((uint8_t *)message, strlen(message));
  vw_wait_tx(); // Wait until the whole message is gone
}
```

after compiling, I am getting an error as

> exit status 1
>   cannot convert 'String' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'void send(char*)'

[image]

Please anyone tell me a way for solving this.
Problem is at transmitter part only. So I posted only about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This should be a comment, but its too long]

> •exit status 1 invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
>   [-fpermissive]

This means that the function you are calling wants a char* as a parameter, but you are passing it a char* that can't be modified.  The chances are that the send function doesn't modify the value in the parameter, so you *might* be OK just casting it, but you might get a runtime error if send does modify the value (a segmentation fault most likely, or just an ugly crash).  If you do you will need to allocate a temporary buffer that is big enough (str.length() + 1) and then copy it into that buffer and pass that to send.

So, try this first:

```
send((char*)voice.c_str());
```

If that fails then try this:

```
char* tempBuffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (voice.length() + 1));
if (tempBuffer)
{
    strncpy(tempBuffer, voice.c_str(), (voice.length() + 1));
    send(tempBuffer);
    free(tempBuffer);
    tempBuffer = 0;
}
```

Of course if the data is always a fixed length then you can allocate an array on the stack instead of mallocing a buffer onto the heap.

Comment: thanking you. It worked very well the first one  send((char*)voice.c_str());    But after that I got another error in transmission. Once I send a string of length 15 characters then after that if I send 16 or more than 15 characters string , it is receiving only up to 15 character in same way the string length is getting fixed and unable to send more length string than previous one.In such a way the length of string receiving is getting reduced. Can you suggest me any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> exit status 1 cannot convert 'String' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'void send(char*)'

The compiler is telling you about the issue. You can access the `String` as a character vector (C string) with the member function [`c_str()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CStr), e.g. `send(voice.c_str());`

You might need to check that it is not too long for the payload in the VirtualWire library.

Cheers!

Comment: I had done what you said then it returned with following error > - exit status 1 invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]